# Picasso Target Null Error for URL file downloading. Java

Tags: java, android, io, imageview, picasso

I am trying to download images off a URL using Picasso API for Android Studio Java. A floating action bar is clicked and a alert dialog is displayed with the image from the URL in it.

I Have Tried the following:
[Picasso Target must not be null error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32355167/picasso-target-must-not-be-null-error).
But my error is still occurring.

This is the code I'm currently using:

```
        FloatingActionButton FabViewImage = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fabPicture);
    if (FabViewImage != null)
        FabViewImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Dialog settingsDialog = new Dialog(TabEmpOrder.this);
                settingsDialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                settingsDialog.setContentView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.order_detail_image_view, null));
                Context context = settingsDialog.getContext();
                settingsDialog.show();

                ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgOrderDetails);
                Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/Tnendik.png").into(imgView);
            }
        });
```

Here is the Error Message it displays

```
08-23 09:54:06.351 25488-25488/dura_art.bigbyte E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: dura_art.bigbyte, PID: 25488
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target must not be null.
at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:618)
at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:601)
at dura_art.bigbyte.TabEmpOrder$1.onClick(TabEmpOrder.java:99)//This is where it breaks
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5697)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22526)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Where did I go wrong? And how can I fix it?

Comment: Initialize your ImageView in onCreate and make sure that R.id.imgOrderDetails indeed refers to the same view.

Comment: so your image is displayed on alert dialog right? Is image view part of dialog layout??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this

```
View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.order_detail_image_view, null);
settingsDialog.setContentView(v);
            Context context = settingsDialog.getContext();
            settingsDialog.show();
ImageView imgView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgOrderDetails);
            Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/Tnendik.png").into(imgView);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the `ImageView` from the layout used for `AlertDialog` so try below code:

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Dialog settingsDialog = new Dialog(TabEmpOrder.this);
            settingsDialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            View layout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.order_detail_image_view;
            ImageView imgView = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.imgOrderDetails);

            settingsDialog.setContentView(layout, null));
            Context context = settingsDialog.getContext();
            settingsDialog.show();


            Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/Tnendik.png").into(imgView);
        }
```

Here your `ImageView` was `null` when passed to `picasso` but now it won't be.